# .htaccess redirecting submain to a folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Does anyone can help me to correct this code? I have a subdomain that point to the root domain and I need to point it to a folder, this code is doing the job but fails when you try to use a folder on the subdomain, when I enter `teste.edirpedro.com.br/pasta` the server change the url to `teste.edirpedro.com.br/teste/pasta`. What is wrong here?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?teste\.edirpedro\.com\.br$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/teste/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /teste/$1
```

Comment: No, just that. It's strange that if I point to `/pasta` it redirects to `/teste/pasta` and if I point to `/pasta/` it redirects rightly to `/pasta/`

Comment: Thanks, I passed the problem to my host, but they are a little slow to respond something. I thing the problem is with the host, because there is only this rule, only at the root directory.

Comment: Nope, my host won't help and the code has a bug. If you enter (http://teste.edirpedro.com.br/pasta) you are redirected and if you enter (http://teste.edirpedro.com.br/pasta/) with a slash at the end, it does right. Where is the error?